# Anyone know of a jQuery Plugin that arranges images like Google Images?

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins

*I do not want Masonry.

If you notice the way Google Images works, the images are 'resized' to align perfectly within the container. In other words the right and left sides are aligned.

When you resize your browser window the images adjust to maintain the look.

I'm interested in the way the images are loaded onto the page, not what happens after you click on them.

Comment: @jhunlio have you seen how Google arranges images?

Comment: if you carefully resize your window you'll notice that the images are not Perfectly aligned, and here we're talking about extensive calculations and algorithms, Images are dynamically adjusting the left margin inside an overflow `DIV` element, the images height is 100%, or less (with top margin) if there's need to gain width to fit the row width with other images.

Comment: If you want to have a fixed *images containers* sizes, I can show you how to do it (supporting modern browsers) in a really simple way. But it'll not look as Google does.

Comment: Based on your requirements, [Gridster](http://gridster.net) seems to be a great fit.

Comment: Gridster...hmm this is interesting. I'm going mess around with that.  Otherwise, I was thinking that one way to do it would be to force all the images into their own individual containers, make each of those containers the same size. And then apply masonry to the parent container which holds all the individual containers. It would look something like the grid view in Adobe Bridge.

Answer (score 1):

I used this:http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/create-a-resizable-image-grid-with-jquery

And then put each of those elements inside a container with masonry.

Also each of my images have the same height but varying widths.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a jQuery plugin that creates a perfect grid using randomly sized elements - you can control the size if you'd like. It's job is to fill in any empty gaps that come from a masonry or isotop layout. Can be fluid or static, supports gutters, also allows for strict typing sizes.

https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Mason

an example - https://drewdahlman.com/experiments/mason/example/fluid_gutters.html

One note is that it requires filler blocks which can be setup however you'd like, or it will copy and duplicate random blocks from the grid.